# Batch File Choice Command and Running code

Tags: batch-file, ping, batch-choice

When using the CHOICE command, is there a way to make other code run at the same time?

For example, I am trying to create a timer that counts up. I want to make it so the choice option appears while the timer is sill running.

```
@echo off
set /a time=0
:up
cls
echo Time: %time%
echo Press "s" to start
CHOICE /c:s /n > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto run1
:run1
cls
echo Time: %time%
echo Press "p" to pause
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set /a time=%time%+1
CHOICE /c:p /n > nul /t 1
if errorlevel 1 goto up
goto run1
```

If this question seems confusing or you don't know what I am asking, post a comment. I am trying to reword this question the best I can.

Comment: Sort of. I just edited it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get a CR control-char
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"

set /a time=0
cls
:up
echo/
echo Time: %time%
set /P "=Press "s" to start: " < NUL
CHOICE /c:s /n

:run1
set /a time=%time%+1
set /P "=Time: %time%, press "p" to pause:!CR!" < NUL
CHOICE /c:px /n /t 1 /d:x > nul
if errorlevel 2 goto run1
echo/
goto up
```

Comment: Even though this code half worked for me, I am happy because I understand some of the commands a little better.